# Why is there discrepancy in conservation of energy and momentum in my modified version of Veritasium's bullet board experiment?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, collision

https://youtu.be/BLYoyLcdGPc

*This is the Veritasium's bullet board experiment: A bullet is shot from beneath a horizontal board. The first time it is shot right underneath its centre of mass, and the second time the shot is shifted a bit to the right (giving the board an angular momentum).*

*Both of the planks rise to the same height, implying that in the second case the board had larger energy (since it also needed to rotate). That is explained by considering that the amount of waste energy lost (in heat, deformation etc) is not fixed. So conserving the momentum, you can always imagine that the amount of waste energy lost in the spinning board (2nd case) is less by assuming that the deformation/heat/sound loss is less.*

My modified experiment is a thought experiment, where I wanted to imagine a hypothetical scenario where the bullet actually went through the board and lost the exact same amount of energy in both the cases (maybe by making the board really thin, and performing the experiment in vacuum, and ignoring wobbling vibrations). I also assume that all of the energy loss is given to the board in each case.

So I'm fixing the energy change of the bullet. Which fixes the change in velocity of the bullet, which fixes the change of linear momentum. That implies both the cases should again reach the same height.

But I also fixed the amount of energy that was lost by the bullet. So the 2nd case *can't* have more energy. Which means it's translational kinetic energy needs to be less. Which means it shouldn't reach the same height (or have the same momentum since mass is same).

My question is:

1)Is there something fundamentally wrong in my thought experiment? Is it physically impossible?

(My hunch is: due to the rotation, the energy loss physically can't be the same for the bullet in both the cases. *Remember however, I've taken really thin boards to limit the amount of time the bullet spends in the boards. But maybe the order of its thinness corresponds to the height it rises. So maybe however thin the board is, it always correspond to a singnificant change in energy in its own order?*)

2) If I remove my assumption that all of the energy loss is given to the board, can a method be imagined where the 2nd case receives more percentage of that lost energy? After all, the deformation is the same. (Otherwise the loss of energy would be different.)

Comment: You can fix the energy change of the bullet, but not the proportion of energy that will stay as total kinetic energy. The initial total energy will be redistributed differently between kinetic E, deformation E and heat in the two examples

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to ask. Is it not even hypothetically possible?

Comment: No, it would violate conservation of momentum